# LibGDX Java Fatal Error when destroying Fixtures

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm making voxel based game, and I have a problem.
I have one Body, that contains 64 Fixtures, every fixture is a block In my game. When i try to delete one of those fixtures I have a java Fatal Error

This is this error

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000066bdf3fe, pid=5632, tid=8388
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b14) (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [gdx-box2d64.dll+0x1f3fe]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000001955f000):  JavaThread "LWJGL Application" [_thread_in_native, id=8388, stack(0x000000001a190000,0x000000001a290000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000010

Registers:
RAX=0x000000001a390080, RBX=0x000000001a390080, RCX=0x000000001a3bcca0, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x000000001a28f150, RBP=0x000000001a28f2a8, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x000000001a3bcca0
R8 =0x000000001a390080, R9 =0x000000001a3bcca0, R10=0x0000000002645e08, R11=0x000000005c997ca0
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000016d733c0, R14=0x000000001a28f2f8, R15=0x000000001955f000
RIP=0x0000000066bdf3fe, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000001a28f150)
0x000000001a28f150:   0000000016d733c0 0000000000000000
0x000000001a28f160:   000000001955f000 0000000019564cf0
0x000000001a28f170:   000000001a390080 000000001a3bcca0
0x000000001a28f180:   0000000002637ced 0000000066be8702
0x000000001a28f190:   000000001a28f798 0000000017193a40
0x000000001a28f1a0:   00000000000003d8 0000000017193a50
0x000000001a28f1b0:   0000000066c1c830 000000001955f1f8
0x000000001a28f1c0:   000000001a28f2f8 000000001955f000
0x000000001a28f1d0:   0000000066c1c8b0 000000001955f1f8
0x000000001a28f1e0:   000000001a28f2f8 000000001955f000
0x000000001a28f1f0:   0000000016d733c0 0000000016d733c0
0x000000001a28f200:   0000000000000020 0000000002645e34
0x000000001a28f210:   000000001a28f798 000000001a28f2a8
0x000000001a28f220:   0000000000000020 0000000002637ced
0x000000001a28f230:   0000000000000000 0000000002645bab
0x000000001a28f240:   000000001955f000 0000000016d733c0 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000066bdf3fe)
0x0000000066bdf3de:   40 00 57 56 53 48 83 ec 20 48 8b 41 58 48 89 cf
0x0000000066bdf3ee:   48 89 d6 f6 80 98 92 01 00 02 0f 85 f2 00 00 00
0x0000000066bdf3fe:   48 39 7e 10 74 19 48 8d 15 55 8b 03 00 48 8d 0d
0x0000000066bdf40e:   d5 8c 03 00 41 b8 de 00 00 00 e8 53 4c 01 00 8b 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x000000001a390080 is an unknown value
RBX=0x000000001a390080 is an unknown value
RCX=0x000000001a3bcca0 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000001a28f150 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001955f000
RBP=0x000000001a28f2a8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001955f000
RSI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDI=0x000000001a3bcca0 is an unknown value
R8 =0x000000001a390080 is an unknown value
R9 =0x000000001a3bcca0 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000002645e08 is at code_begin+840 in an Interpreter codelet
method entry point (kind = native)  [0x0000000002645ac0, 0x0000000002646420]  2400 bytes
R11=0x000000005c997ca0 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13={method} {0x0000000016d733c8} 'jniDestroyFixture' '(JJJ)V' in 'com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World'
R14=0x000000001a28f2f8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001955f000
R15=0x000000001955f000 is a thread


Stack: [0x000000001a190000,0x000000001a290000],  sp=0x000000001a28f150,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [gdx-box2d64.dll+0x1f3fe]
C  [gdx-box2d64.dll+0x28702]
C  0x0000000002645e34

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.jniDestroyFixture(JJJ)V+0
j  com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.destroyFixture(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body;Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Fixture;)V+13
j  com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body.destroyFixture(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Fixture;)V+6
j  blocks.Part.close()V+22
j  ingens.Ingens.create()V+250
j  com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop()V+29
j  com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run()V+27
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00000000023ae000 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=9792, stack(0x0000000002430000,0x0000000002530000)]
=>0x000000001955f000 JavaThread "LWJGL Application" [_thread_in_native, id=8388, stack(0x000000001a190000,0x000000001a290000)]
  0x00000000171de800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2948, stack(0x0000000018de0000,0x0000000018ee0000)]
  0x0000000017195000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5456, stack(0x00000000188e0000,0x00000000189e0000)]
  0x0000000017184800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6792, stack(0x00000000187e0000,0x00000000188e0000)]
  0x000000001717d800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10096, stack(0x00000000186e0000,0x00000000187e0000)]
  0x000000001717b800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4304, stack(0x00000000185e0000,0x00000000186e0000)]
  0x0000000017186800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6228, stack(0x00000000184e0000,0x00000000185e0000)]
  0x0000000002627000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9460, stack(0x00000000183e0000,0x00000000184e0000)]
  0x000000000261e000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1020, stack(0x00000000182e0000,0x00000000183e0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000017147800 VMThread [stack: 0x00000000181e0000,0x00000000182e0000] [id=5568]
  0x0000000018a20000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000018ee0000,0x0000000018fe0000] [id=7472]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 12899K [0x00000000d5d80000, 0x00000000d8800000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 38% used [0x00000000d5d80000,0x00000000d6a18df0,0x00000000d7e00000)
  from space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d8300000,0x00000000d8300000,0x00000000d8800000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d7e00000,0x00000000d7e00000,0x00000000d8300000)
 ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 0K [0x0000000081800000, 0x0000000086d80000, 0x00000000d5d80000)
  object space 87552K, 0% used [0x0000000081800000,0x0000000081800000,0x0000000086d80000)
 Metaspace       used 7284K, capacity 7421K, committed 7680K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 723K, capacity 754K, committed 768K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x00000000119f0000,0x0000000011df0000] byte_map_base: 0x00000000115e4000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000005cf74040
 Begin Bits: [0x00000000124a0000, 0x0000000014440000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000014440000, 0x00000000163e0000)

Polling page: 0x0000000002370000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=2131Kb max_used=2143Kb free=243628Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002630000, 0x00000000028a0000, 0x0000000011630000]
 total_blobs=917 nmethods=423 adapters=407
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.564 Thread 0x0000000017195000 nmethod 417 0x0000000002840290 code [0x0000000002840460, 0x0000000002840c58]
Event: 0.564 Thread 0x0000000017195000  418       3       java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream::close (34 bytes)
Event: 0.564 Thread 0x0000000017195000 nmethod 418 0x000000000283fd10 code [0x000000000283fe80, 0x0000000002840178]
Event: 0.566 Thread 0x0000000017195000  420       3       com.badlogic.gdx.utils.LongMap::hash2 (22 bytes)
Event: 0.566 Thread 0x0000000017195000 nmethod 420 0x0000000002844510 code [0x0000000002844660, 0x00000000028447f0]
Event: 0.566 Thread 0x0000000017195000  422       3       com.badlogic.gdx.utils.LongMap::hash3 (22 bytes)
Event: 0.566 Thread 0x0000000017195000 nmethod 422 0x0000000002844890 code [0x00000000028449e0, 0x0000000002844b70]
Event: 0.566 Thread 0x0000000017195000  421       3       com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array::add (48 bytes)
Event: 0.566 Thread 0x0000000017195000 nmethod 421 0x0000000002844c10 code [0x0000000002844dc0, 0x00000000028451e8]
Event: 0.567 Thread 0x0000000017184800  423       4       java.lang.StringBuilder::append (8 bytes)

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.130 Thread 0x00000000023ae000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d60a42c0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.130 Thread 0x00000000023ae000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d60a4478) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.131 Thread 0x00000000023ae000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d60a7f70) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.131 Thread 0x00000000023ae000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d60a8128) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.236 Thread 0x00000000023ae000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d61a55e0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.236 Thread 0x00000000023ae000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d61a7208) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.236 Thread 0x00000000023ae000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d61a82c8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.236 Thread 0x00000000023ae000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d61ad2c0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.236 Thread 0x00000000023ae000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d61ade68) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.236 Thread 0x00000000023ae000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d61ae9e0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u45\3457\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.563 loading class com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/CircleShape
Event: 0.563 loading class com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/CircleShape done
Event: 0.563 loading class com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/EdgeShape
Event: 0.563 loading class com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/EdgeShape done
Event: 0.565 loading class com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/ChainShape
Event: 0.565 loading class com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/ChainShape done
Event: 0.565 loading class blocks/BlockType
Event: 0.565 loading class blocks/BlockType done
Event: 0.566 loading class java/io/PrintWriter
Event: 0.566 loading class java/io/PrintWriter done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff7c6380000 - 0x00007ff7c63b7000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\javaw.exe
0x00007ffc789e0000 - 0x00007ffc78b8c000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffc78420000 - 0x00007ffc7855e000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffc75d00000 - 0x00007ffc75e15000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffc746d0000 - 0x00007ffc7475e000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x00007ffc61710000 - 0x00007ffc61763000     C:\Windows\AppPatch\AppPatch64\AcGenral.DLL
0x00007ffc76410000 - 0x00007ffc764ba000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffc75900000 - 0x00007ffc7592e000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
0x00007ffc78160000 - 0x00007ffc781b4000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x00007ffc78860000 - 0x00007ffc789d7000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x00007ffc77b40000 - 0x00007ffc77cd4000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x00007ffc76520000 - 0x00007ffc77a38000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ffc75130000 - 0x00007ffc75151000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x00007ffc78370000 - 0x00007ffc7841a000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffc6ee10000 - 0x00007ffc6ee2e000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
0x00007ffc78570000 - 0x00007ffc786b1000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffc764c0000 - 0x00007ffc76519000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x00007ffc77dc0000 - 0x00007ffc77fd1000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
0x00007ffc76060000 - 0x00007ffc761b1000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ffc75b30000 - 0x00007ffc75b45000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
0x00007ffc740e0000 - 0x00007ffc74192000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHCORE.dll
0x00007ffc77a40000 - 0x00007ffc77a76000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x00007ffc78000000 - 0x00007ffc78152000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x00007ffc73c00000 - 0x00007ffc73e7a000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9600.17810_none_6240b9c7ecbd0bda\COMCTL32.dll
0x000000005d5b0000 - 0x000000005d682000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x000000005c770000 - 0x000000005cff3000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ffc6e720000 - 0x00007ffc6e729000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ffc73280000 - 0x00007ffc732a2000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ffc732b0000 - 0x00007ffc732ba000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ffc77ce0000 - 0x00007ffc77ce7000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ffc786d0000 - 0x00007ffc7872a000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ffc72fa0000 - 0x00007ffc72fca000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ffc786c0000 - 0x00007ffc786c9000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x00007ffc75cb0000 - 0x00007ffc75cff000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x00007ffc74930000 - 0x00007ffc74958000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x000000005e4a0000 - 0x000000005e4af000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\verify.dll
0x000000005d580000 - 0x000000005d5a9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\java.dll
0x000000005e480000 - 0x000000005e496000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\zip.dll
0x0000000065580000 - 0x0000000065616000     C:\Users\Jakub\AppData\Local\Temp\libgdxJakub\88a71714\gdx64.dll
0x00007ffc75240000 - 0x00007ffc75260000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x00007ffc74f80000 - 0x00007ffc74fb6000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x00007ffc755f0000 - 0x00007ffc75616000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
0x00007ffc75930000 - 0x00007ffc75993000     C:\Windows\system32\bcryptprimitives.dll
0x00007ffc759a0000 - 0x00007ffc759ab000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000000005d560000 - 0x000000005d57a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\net.dll
0x00007ffc75350000 - 0x00007ffc753a9000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x00007ffc6e3d0000 - 0x00007ffc6e3fa000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x00007ffc6e4c0000 - 0x00007ffc6e4ca000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINNSI.DLL
0x00007ffc6e410000 - 0x00007ffc6e426000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x00007ffc6e090000 - 0x00007ffc6e0aa000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x000000005d540000 - 0x000000005d551000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\nio.dll
0x0000000180000000 - 0x0000000180053000     C:\Users\Jakub\AppData\Local\Temp\libgdxJakub\dc0f0009\lwjgl64.dll
0x00007ffc68110000 - 0x00007ffc6823b000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\OPENGL32.dll
0x00007ffc737d0000 - 0x00007ffc737fe000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll
0x00007ffc69310000 - 0x00007ffc69408000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DDRAW.dll
0x00007ffc73b50000 - 0x00007ffc73b59000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x00000000192e0000 - 0x0000000019344000     C:\Users\Jakub\AppData\Local\Temp\libgdxJakub\dc0f0009\OpenAL64.dll
0x00007ffc747f0000 - 0x00007ffc747fb000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ffc74800000 - 0x00007ffc74929000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x00007ffc787a0000 - 0x00007ffc78856000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\clbcatq.dll
0x00007ffc5d270000 - 0x00007ffc5d30d000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dsound.dll
0x00007ffc75ad0000 - 0x00007ffc75b16000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\POWRPROF.dll
0x00007ffc731c0000 - 0x00007ffc73230000     C:\Windows\System32\MMDevApi.dll
0x00007ffc6e300000 - 0x00007ffc6e37e000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\AUDIOSES.DLL
0x00007ffc77cf0000 - 0x00007ffc77db1000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x00007ffc73e80000 - 0x00007ffc73ea1000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x000000001a490000 - 0x000000001ac60000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ig75icd64.dll
0x00007ffc70260000 - 0x00007ffc706ae000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\igdusc64.dll
0x00007ffc735d0000 - 0x00007ffc73662000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\mscms.dll
0x00007ffc5c650000 - 0x00007ffc5c691000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\icm32.dll
0x0000000066bc0000 - 0x0000000066c7b000     C:\Users\Jakub\AppData\Local\Temp\libgdxJakub\364d8f01\gdx-box2d64.dll
0x00007ffc707b0000 - 0x00007ffc70939000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1250 
java_command: ingens.desktop.DesktopLauncher
java_class_path (initial): D:\Ingens2\desktop\bin;D:\Ingens2\core\bin;C:\Users\Jakub\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx\1.6.2\b70b1eb9da71076aa47ac8932b42358b00db84a0\gdx-1.6.2.jar;C:\Users\Jakub\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-box2d\1.6.2\b4406b97b35d7caf7111400ceebc8b92c8998168\gdx-box2d-1.6.2.jar;C:\Users\Jakub\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-backend-lwjgl\1.6.2\2f75f0807864ffc2f7cbf25a6e43543ce63d21a5\gdx-backend-lwjgl-1.6.2.jar;C:\Users\Jakub\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-platform\1.6.2\c3f948f4394338a5411b1f6f2791a608a9a42286\gdx-platform-1.6.2-natives-desktop.jar;C:\Users\Jakub\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-box2d-platform\1.6.2\47ac6e45b6994f6a2b15e42fd567cece6c7bec7c\gdx-box2d-platform-1.6.2-natives-desktop.jar;C:\Users\Jakub\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.2\a9d80fe5935c7a9149f6584d9777cfd471f65489\lwjgl-2.9.2.jar;C:\Users\Jakub\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.2\4b9e37300a87799856e0bd15ed81663cdb6b0947\lwjgl_util-2.9.2.jar;C:\Users\Jakub\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.jlayer\jlayer\1.0.1-gdx\7cca83cec5c1b2f011362f4d85aabd71a73b049d\jlayer-1.0.1-gdx.jar;C:\Users\Jakub\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jcraft\jorbis\0.0.17\8872d22b293e8f5d7d56ff92be966e6dc28ebdc6\jorbis-0.0.17.jar;C:\Users\Jakub\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.2\510c7d317f5e9e700b9cfaac5fd38bdebf0702e0\lwjgl-platform-2.9.2-natives-windows.jar;C:\Users\Jakub\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.2\d276cdf61fe2b516c7b7f4aa1b8dea91dbdc8d56\lwjgl-platform-2.9.2-natives-linux.jar;C:\Users\Jakub\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.2\d55b46b40b40249d627a83a7f7f22649709d70c3\lwjgl-platform-2.9.2-natives-osx.jar;C:\Users\Jakub\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\idmu\common;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\android-sdk\tools;C:\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
USERNAME=Jakub
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 69 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 8.1 , 64 bit Build 9600 (6.3.9600.17415)

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 69 stepping 1, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2

Memory: 4k page, physical 8290116k(4496800k free), swap 16678724k(11618076k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_45-b14), built on Apr 10 2015 10:34:15 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Fri Jun 26 23:00:19 2015
elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)
```

Those are my classes that I use:

- My main class

public class Ingens extends ApplicationAdapter implements Disposable,
        InputProcessor {

```
public static boolean set = false;

int where = 0;

float time = 0;

int place;

public static PrintWriter map;
File mapa;
public static String load;

public static Scanner in;

SpriteBatch batch;
OrthographicCamera gameCamera;

public static int playerPosition;

public static int playerRegionX;
public static int playerRegionY;

public static int playerPartX;
public static int playerPartY;

public static World world;

Box2DDebugRenderer render;

Contacts contacts;

// ALL BLOCKS, ONE BODY, MANY FIXTURES
public static BodyDef blocksB;
public static FixtureDef blocksF;
public static Body allBlocks;
public static PolygonShape square;

Fixture[] fix = new Fixture[64]; // At start we create world!
Fixture[] rendered = new Fixture[64];

public int BLOCK1 = 2;
public int BLOCK2 = 4;

Part part;

@Override
public void create() {

    Textures.textureInitialization();

    Box2D.init();

    // BOX2D STUFF
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, gravity), true);
    contacts = new Contacts();
    world.setContactListener(contacts);
    render = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

    // World made of blocks, one body, many fixtures
    blocksB = new BodyDef();
    blocksB.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
    blocksB.position.set(0, 0); // if bigger or smaller than 0, we need to
                                // /PPM
    allBlocks = world.createBody(blocksB);
    square = new PolygonShape();
    blocksF = new FixtureDef();
    blocksF.filter.categoryBits = Vars.BIT_COMMON_BLOCK;
    blocksF.filter.maskBits = Vars.BIT_COMMON_ENTITY;

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    gameCamera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    mapa = new File("map.txt");

    try {
        in = new Scanner(mapa);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    part = new Part(0, 0);

    part.saveMap();

    part.close();

}

@Override
public void render() {

    // LOADING MAP

    System.out.println(time);

    // END OF MAP LOADING

    update();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.6f, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    render.render(world, gameCamera.combined);

    batch.begin();

    Player.draw(world, batch);

    // part.draw(batch);

    batch.end();

    time += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    /**
     * // PLAYER Player.work(batch); // PLAYER
     * 
     * PartGenerator.draw(batch);
     **/
    // that should always be at the end
    world.step(1 / 60f, 6, 2);

}

public void update() {

    Input();

    // PLAYER
    // playerRegionX = (int) Math.ceil(Player.player.x / 8 / 32);
    // playerRegionY = (int) Math.ceil(Player.player.y / 8 / 32);

    // playerPartX = (int) Math.ceil(Player.player.x / 32);
    // playerPartY = (int) Math.ceil(Player.player.y / 32);

    // playerPosition = (int) ((Math.ceil(Player.player.x / 32) +
    // Math.ceil(Player.player.y / 32) * regionSizeX));

    // PLAYER

    gameCamera.update();
    gameCamera.position.set(Player.player.getX(), Player.player.getY()
            + Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 10f / PPM, 0);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(gameCamera.combined);
    gameCamera.zoom = 5f / PPM;

}

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    Gdx.app.exit();

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    world.dispose();
    render.dispose();
    Gdx.app.exit();
}

public void Input() {
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)) {
        if (contacts.playerOnGround == true) {
            Player.player.jump();
        }
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)) {
        Player.player.moveX(4);
    } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)) {
        Player.player.moveX(-4);
    } else {
        Player.player.moveX(0);
    }
}
```

}

- BlockClass

public class Block extends Fixture{

```
BlockType type;
Shape shape;
float texX;
float texY;

public Block(Body body, long addr, Shape shape, Filter filter, BlockType type) {
    super(body, addr);
    body.createFixture(shape, 0);
    this.type = type;
}

public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float x, float y){
    batch.draw(type.texture, x, y, 64 / PPM, 64 / PPM);
}
```

}

- Part Class

public class Part {

```
Block[] blocks = new Block[64];

int x;
int y;


public Part(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    for(int ID = 0 + x * 64; ID < 64 + x * 64 ; ID++){
        int fY = (int)Math.ceil(ID / (8)) + y * 8; // Fixture Y
        int fX = ID - fY * 8 + x * 8; // Fixture X
            square.setAsBox(32 / PPM, 32 / PPM, new Vector2(fX * 64 / PPM, fY * 64 / PPM - (x * 64 * 8 / PPM)), 0);
            blocks[ID] = new Block(allBlocks, 0, square, blocksF.filter, BlockType.DIRT);
            blocks[ID].texX = fX * 64 / PPM - 32 / PPM;
            blocks[ID].texY = fY * 64 / PPM - 32 / PPM;
            blocks[ID].setUserData(blocks[ID].type);
    }

}

public void draw(SpriteBatch batch){
    for(int ID = 0 + x * 64; ID < 64 + x * 64 ; ID++){
    blocks[ID].draw(batch, blocks[ID].texX, blocks[ID].texY - (x * 64 * 8 / PPM));
    }
}

public void saveMap(){
    try {
        map = new PrintWriter("map.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    for(int ID = 0 + x * 64; ID < 64 + x * 64 ; ID++){
        map.println(blocks[ID].getUserData() + ",");
    }

    map.close();

}

public void close(){
    for(int ID = 0 + x * 64; ID < 64 + x * 64 ; ID++){
        allBlocks.destroyFixture(blocks[ID]);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: It also happen when i try to add a filter to fixture.

Answer (score 1):

Box2D doesn't allow you to delete anything while it is processing the current timestep. This means that you need to wait for B2World.step() to return before you can delete anything. So if you are deleting a fixture in a call that comes from ContactListener or something it will crash. Instead you should mark the fixture with a boolean and then delete it after the physics simulation is done computing.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure to do all box2d operations from the same thread.